# Combine two queries with count function for a single result set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in a `mySQL` database

```
Table 1 [Orders]
DateOpened (date), 
revenue

Table 2 [Movements]
DateStarted (date), 
DateStopped (date)
```

For any given date, there could be 0 or more entries in Table 1 and for Table 2, there could be 0 or more entries for both `DateStarted` or `DateStopped` (both DateStarted and DateStopped could be the **same** day or **different**)

I want to query these tables for a date range (eg: a month) and get a result set for each date that has some data in this form:

```
date, sum(revenue), num_orders (count of orders for the date), num_movements (count of movements for the date)
```

I have created two separate queries which accomplish each part but I can't figure out how to combine them so that I can achieve a single efficient query and not have to merge the result sets in code.  The thing I seem to be getting hung up on is the count() function applying correctly.

Here are the working existing queries:

```
select count(*) as total_movements, movement_date
from (
    select dropoffdate as movement_date
    from bb_movement
    where (dropoffdate >= '2013-01-01' and dropoffdate <= '2013-06-30') 
    union all
    select pickupdate as movement_date
    from bb_movement
    where (pickupdate >= '2013-01-01' and pickupdate <= '2013-06-30')
) as t3
group by movement_date
order by movement_date asc

select count(*) as num_orders, sum(order_amount) as revenue, dateopened as date_opened
from bb_order
where (dateopened >= '2013-01-01' and dateopened <= '2013-06-30') 
group by dateopened
order by dateopened asc
```

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bb_movement` (
  `movementid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `orderid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT
  `dropoffdate` date NOT NULL,
  `pickupdate` date NOT NULL )

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bb_order` (
  `orderid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `movementid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dateopened` date NOT NULL,
  `order_amount` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' 
}

Comment: **`Desc table bb_movement and bb_order`** and What actually do you want to Achieve.

Comment: I have shown in the body what I want to achieve - for every date in the range that I specify, I should get a row returned when there exists 1 or more orders (count of orders and count of revenue for these matching orders) or a count of movements (either matching dropoffdate or pickupdate or both).

Comment: What are columns for table bb_movement and bb_order

Comment: for the purposes of this question, I think the above is sufficient isn't it? I'll edit the main question and add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: It required a union of the source tables with the appropriate aggregation functions in the main select

```
 SELECT mv_date, sum(mv_count), sum(order_count), sum(order_revenue)
FROM (
    select dateopened as mv_date, 0 as mv_count, count(*) as order_count, sum(order_amount) as order_revenue
    from bb_order
    where (dateopened >= '2013-01-01' and dateopened <= '2013-06-30')
    group by mv_date
    union all
    SELECT dropoffdate AS mv_date, COUNT( * ) AS mv_count, 0 as order_count, 0 as order_revenue
    FROM bb_movement
    WHERE (dropoffdate >=  '2013-01-01' AND dropoffdate <=  '2013-06-30')
    group by mv_date
    UNION  all
    SELECT pickupdate AS mv_date, COUNT( * ) AS mv_count, 0 as order_count, 0 as order_revenue
    FROM bb_movement
    WHERE (pickupdate >=  '2013-01-01' AND pickupdate <=  '2013-06-30')
    group by mv_date
 ) mv
group by mv_date
order by mv_date
```